# SQL update a column that lost order?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a situation and I am weak at SQL. Here it is.

I have archived items, that are stored with a number. It is like this in the database table.

```
RowId   Number  CaseId
234        1       787
235        2       787
236        3       787
237        4       787
238        5       787
```

This is how it looks when first inserted. But after deleting, take Number 3 is deleted, It is now like this on DB.

```
RowId   Number  CaseId
234        1       787
235        2       787   
237        4       787
238        5       787
```

3 is gone but what I need is this.

```
RowId   Number  CaseId
234        1       787
235        2       787   
237        3       787
238        4       787
```

The numbers should be updated too. But I can't figure out a way to do this. By the way, there are many CaseId's. I won't update the whole table, I will select it by a CaseId. Can you tell me how to do this? I am using C# .NET

Should I take them in to a list (the way they are ordered from Select query) and check one by one and then update them? I can write the check one by one on C# but I think it won't be efficient. What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: do you need to store the "Number" can't you just calculated it when you select off the table?

Comment: Then you do not need any "true" column "Number". Simply OrderBy RowId and use row_number()

Comment: In the case I will suggest not to store Number in your database. Whenever you need above result just write a SELECT query with Row_number(). for more details see her: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: I am not allowed to change the DB Table but I will try ordering them by their RowId now

Comment: The RowId is actually my ArchiveId but I guess the name doesn't matter right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does Number have to be updated in the database itself?  If not, do you even need to store this?  Also are you writing SQL queries?  Or just using Entity Framework?  If you are writing actual queries, and if you just want the row number when you select the data back you can try something like:

```
SELECT RowId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowId ASC) AS [Number], CaseId 
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE CaseID = 787
```

EDIT:  As pointed out by @Mike in the comments, it would probably make sense to make a view out of this.  You can remove [Number] from the primary table and make a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView 
AS 
    SELECT RowId, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CaseId ORDER BY RowId ASC) AS Number, 
    CaseId FROM MyTable
```

The PARTITION statement will make sure that Number resets for every distinct RowId

Comment: +1 - This is a much better solution if it's possible and further a view or stored procedure could be created that could still be leveraged by the Entity Framework.

Comment: I have to store the Number in the DB. It is used for search. Can I do this in the database without retrieving it first then updating?

Comment: @Ada, you can certainly query against a view and unless you find that it causes **severe** performance issues I would do it that way. Storing an integer value like the one in this question in a table is much like storing the total price of a sales order - it's a bad idea because it's very hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with ROW_NUMBER(), a table variable and an update across two tables!

```
-- Declare a variable to hold case id

-- This can easily be moved into the signature
-- of a sproc.
DECLARE @caseId INT;
SELECT @caseId = 787;


-- Table variable to hold results
DECLARE @newOrder TABLE 
(
   CaseId int,
   RowId int,
   SortOrder int
)

-- Use row number to work out the new sort order
-- positions
INSERT INTO 
  @newOrder
SELECT
  CaseId,
  RowId,
  ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY [Number]) AS SortOrder
FROM
  [Cases]
WHERE
  CaseId = @caseId


-- Finally, perform a multi-table update using
-- the new sort orders from the table variable
UPDATE
  c
SET
  [Number] = o.SortOrder
FROM
  Cases c,
  @newOrder o
WHERE
  c.RowId = o.RowId
AND c.CaseId = @caseId
```